# Mean value theorem problem with typo/missing info?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

If a function f is differentiable on the reals and f (1)=1, f (2)=3, and f (3)=3, is there necessarily a point c in (1,3) so that f'(c)=1/2?

A simple application of the mean value theorem does not work. 
 I can't use the intermediate value theorem on f'(x) since it might not be continuous. 
Anyway,  I suspect that this problem contains a typo or missing information.  Is this possible?

Comment: I'd guess problem statement just forgot to mention $f$ is *continuously* differentiable on the reals.

Comment: Thanks ☺  so i should probably ask if that is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need to assume $f'$ is continuous. We have $f'(a) = 2$ for some $a\in (1,2)$ and $f'(b) = 0$ for some $b\in (2,3).$ By the Darboux property for derivatives, there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f'(c) = 1/2.$

Comment: Thanks☺, that is interesting.   I was not aware of that theorem.